# incorrect column specifier for column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have:

```
create table `products`
(
    `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
    `price` float(255),
    `weight` int(11),
    `sku` varchar(255),
    `stock_level` int(11),
    `image` mediumblob(1000),
    `search_engine_name` varchar(255),
    `description` varchar(1000),
    `url` varchar(255),
    `category` varchar(255),
    primary key (`id`)
);
```

MySql outputs: "Incorrect column specifier for column 'price'

Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`float(255)` is not valid when specifying the data type.

You can omit the value in the brackets, e.g. just have `float` by itself or specify the value in the brackets using something like `float(7,4)` (see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html) for information on what the values mean...you may need to customise these depending on what you're intending to store in the column)

Comment: I'd probably go with [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) for any currency columns

Comment: why decimal over integer?