# db:schema:load error after db:schema:dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fresh on RoR. I get really confused when I updated my database. I added some tables in my database, and then I want to update schema.rb, so I use `rake db:schema:dump`. Everything goes fine. Immediately after the previous command, I use `rake db:schema:load`, but there is an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect column specifier for column 'partition': CREATE TABLE `ab_test_result` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `model_id` int(11), `group_id` int(11), `kpi` varchar(255), `related_info` varchar(255), `category` varchar(255), `task_group_run_id` int(11), `timestamp` datetime, `partition` float(64), `actual_partition` float(64)) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

How does this happen? What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347282/incorrect-column-specifier-for-column
Take a look at this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So you mean I have to modify the schema.rb manually? Why the generated file is incorrect..?

Comment: No do not change the schema file directly, if you done something wrong then delete and repeat same work.

Comment: My thoughts exactly... `schema.rb` shouldn't need to be modified directly. It looks like the dump is not mysql compatible. You can create migration to change the datatype to decimal though. Then your dumps should be compatible with mysql. Check here : http://blog.mustmodify.com/2010/06/28/mysql-says-incorrect-column-specifier-for-column-x
You need to alter the same column which is giving you errors.

Answer (score 0):

schema.rb is handled by the migrations. You don't need to dump - load each time.

Generate a migration:

```
rails generate migration foo_bar
```

you write your migration's code and then

```
rake db:migrate
```

schema.rb is updated if the migration succeeds

Comment: I think his problem is not regarding migrations but due to the mysql incompatible code generated in schema. I may be wrong of course.